# How to Use Local Database in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing an app which will have a already existing database database.db file.
I have searched a lot but all the solutions that are available for windows phone 7 are not working properly. Is there any running solution on how to implement sqlite of already existing database ? I have also tried WP7Sqliteclient but that is also not working properly. Can anyone direct me in right direction.
I have set build property to resource.

```
Sqlite3.Vdbe Prepare()
{
    Sqlite3.Vdbe ppStmt=new Sqlite3.Vdbe();
    if (Sqlite3.sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, CommandText, CommandText.Length, ref ppStmt, 0) != Sqlite3.SQLITE_OK)
        throw new SQLiteException(Sqlite3.sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
    BindAll(ppStmt);    // here is exception 
    return ppStmt;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `all the solutions for windows phone 7 are not working properly`? Which ones? What's the problem those solutions gave you?

Comment: i have tried sqlite client for windows phone but there are exeception in sqliteclient.cs file  Sqlite3.Vdbe Prepare()
        {
            Sqlite3.Vdbe ppStmt=new Sqlite3.Vdbe();
            int n=Sqlite3.sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, CommandText, CommandText.Length, ref ppStmt, 0);
            if ( n!= Sqlite3.SQLITE_OK)
                throw new SQLiteException(n,SQLiteLastError());
            BindAll(ppStmt);
            return ppStmt;
        } 
at bindall(ppstmt) like An exception of type 'SQLiteClient.SQLiteException' occurred in Community.CsharpSqlite.WP.DLL but was not handled in user code

Comment: Then why didn't you post that at first? What's the exception message? Any inner exceptions?